# Very strange thing in python3

Tags: python, int, long-integer

```
print(int( 342342342342342342 / 10 ))
```

The output is

> 34234234234234236

I do not understand where the 6 comes from! I also tried "long" which gives an error.

Comment: Pretty sure it is to do with `float` Representation Error. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html or https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: `342342342342342342 / 10` → `3.4234234234234236e+16` → [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better using the integer division // operator.

```
print( 342342342342342342 // 10 )
```

As others have commented, floating points in python have some interesting results.

The common example of this is:

```
int(2.5)
```

Returns

```
2
```